# Distractions in software testing

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing

What are the distractions you face daily while doing testing in your office? Are there any steps to cope up with those, like how do you manage to get the job done with utmost quality in between those distractions? Could you give any examples?

Comment: This question seems more like general views question and is not related to particular problem. As the distractions depend on your Seating, Office space, Experience level, Mental and Emotional status etc. You need to make your question more problem specific which is being faced by you.

Comment: Yes sure, you can take cues from here and apply these to other fields as well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be better answered at workspace.stackexchange.com

Comment: old question, but still worth re-opening. It's one of the few questions which are really about the profession of testing and not about general tools, code or development processes

Answer (score 1):

One question:

> What is your office space like?

Distractions often are [ubiquitous](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/12/29.html). You can only try to circumvent. Headphones is one option, changing work hours is another. Changing your [expectations](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000339.html) is a third.

So what you need to do is:

1. Find out average/acceptable performance. You may not have a problem at all.
2. Detect production breaking habits, circumstances and possibly colleagues.
3. Omit, avoid, condition:

   - Change your own behaviour. Come in early when everyone else comes in late for example.
   - Acquire headphones, turn your desk to the wall, whatever works best.
   - Colleagues often are hardest to cope with when breaking your concentration with frequent easy to solve questions or just plain chitchat. Set aside fixed working hours for uninterrupted work, COMMUNICATE these with the reason, put up a sign on your desk while these last.

References:
http://www.joelonsoftware.com/

Comment: Some how I agree to this as I have felt that during weekends if I go to office I can accomplish the same task in much less time that on a normal working day when everybody is around.. Thanks so much for these points.

Answer (score 0):

I try the following things when I am getting distracted while working:

- I work at lunch time, usually when everyone leaves for lunch.
- Meetings are one more distractions. So if there is no planned meeting, I would skip them off.
- Listening to music or I just keep headset to make myself focus.
- If some tasks got delayed due to unplanned meetings/discussions - I would try to complete when everyone leaves office or come early and finish the task first.
- I try to keep myself away from group of testers sits together, without unnecessary discussions.